# Meaning of \b in .Net Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, .net-framework, c#

Microsoft has a [nifty quick reference card](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/4/D240EBF6-A9BA-4E4F-A63F-AEB6DA0B921C/Regular%20expressions%20quick%20reference.pdf) for .Net Regular Expressions.

But it seems to list `\b` as both matching Backspace and also matching "On word boundary".

Which is it?  Can `\b` really do both?  How can you be precise about which one you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure why you asked a C#/.Net question here when you have 27k on Stack Overflow where this belongs, topically.

Comment: The Visual Studio IDE amd Powershell both use .Net expressions.   I came across this question in the context of using the IDE.  Searching and Editing files is more of a SuperUser task than a programming problem.

Comment: I see, thanks. Maybe you can clarify the context, e.g. show a screenshot of the IDE or explain the searching files part? Then I'd say it's fine to stay here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\b` means "word boundary" outside of character classes (also called character sets) and "backspace" inside character classes.

Here it means a word boundary:

```
\bhello\b
```

Here it means a backspace

```
[\b]
```

See this Microsoft reference: [Character Escapes in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
PERL regex has the same [definition](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/usr/rgs/mosaic/pl-regex.html) for `\b`.

Comment: Agreed, per this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MarkAllen: Added your link to my post. Thanks.

Comment: From a quick LinqPad check, `\b` is the only `\[a-zA-Z]` that is defined for both a standalone backslash and as a character class that returns a different match set.